# Setting of StackLayout's dimension

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to set the height of StackLayout, but it does not work.

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Component.onCompleted: console.log('item height:'+height)

    StackLayout {
        id: Part1
        width: parent.width
        height: 0.6*parent.height
        anchors.top: parent.top
        Component.onCompleted: console.log('part1 height:'+height)
        
        Item {
            id: item1
        }
        Item {
            id: item2
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: Part2
        width: parent.width
        height: 0.4*parent.height
        anchors.top: Part1.bottom
        Component.onCompleted: console.log('part2 height:'+height)
        
        Item {
            id: item3
        }
        Item {
            id: item4
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
qml: item height:480
qml: part2 height:192
qml: part1 height:480
```

Now the RowLayout's height is correctly set, but the StackLayout's is not, whose height is always the same as its parent. So how to set it correctly?

Comment: Neither `StackLayout` nor `RowLayout` have defined `anchors`, so both are positioned at the top of the `Item`.

Comment: @Thomenson I forgot to add that. But the StackLayout's height is still wrong though.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me then (apart from capital letter named ids). Maybe could you explain what makes you to think that StackLayout heigh is incorrect? Did your print that value or is something wrong visually?

Comment: @Thomenson Yes, I printed that value, and it is visually wrong also. I added the code which output height values.

Comment: Well, that is strange enough since again, for me the correct values are printed. Could you write what is the parent of the main `Item`? Maybe you can consider also rebuilding whole project?

Comment: @Thomenson I found out the bug. The height is reset by other module. Thanks.